# Ping doesnt work but wireshark detecting ICMP request and reply

Tags: ping, wireshark

I am running into a weird issue and would be grateful if anyone of you can add information.

I have configured two different subnets and as a test. I am trying to ping one machine at 10.10.11.9/30 (on one subnet) from another machine 10.10.11.1/30 (on a different subnet). The ping doesn't work (rightly so).

However, when I try to detect the same in Wireshark, instead of showing "unreachable" messages, it shows normal ICMP requests and replys. Its as if packets are finding their way...

I have attached screenshot
[image]
for ping as well as Wireshark

I did try to compute headerchecksum in IP Packets but even doing that, checksums of packets captured in Wireshark seems correct -- while ping shows all packets are lost.

Can anyone add info?

Thanks alot

Comment: Check the firewall on the system you send/recieve the pings if it filters out ICMP responses.

Comment: Try to clear the ARP cache with `arp -d` in an administrative command prompt. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Unless I missunderstood, are the two hosts actually in different subnets? It doesn't look like it, so wireshark shows the correct data. What Subnetmasks did you assign to the clients?

Comment: @Albin Yes they are different subnets. I assigned both IP addresses as/30 but Network ID of both machines is different and so is the broadcast id

Comment: @harrymc I tried but it doesnt work.

Comment: It shouldn't send out any ICMP to different subnets directly (at least as far as I remember my network class). It has to send it through a router, a static route, some "exotic" configuration like "proxy-arp" etc. What happens on layer 2? How does the IP address gets resolved to a MAC address? I think this will lead you to the solution why there's a response in the first place.

Comment: Which of those 2 systems is wireshark running on?

Comment: I added so info into the question (source and destination mainly), please check if it is right.

Comment: @Bib it's not important, it can be a third machine on a "replication port" (not sure if this is the correct term) for all that matters.

Comment: @Albin, it IS important. If that is on the target system, then it shows routing is working one way and is being replied to. If it's on a replication port in the source network, then that shows routing is working both ways. If it is on the source system, then it shows routing is correct and it is receiving the replies and the problem is limited to that one system.

Comment: @Bib yeah you are right, it might give us additional hints if we know where the packet capturing takes place.

Comment: Did you find out anything yet about where the frames (layer 2) are being sent to? Directly to the client or via a router?

Comment: I wonder if something in your network stack is choking on your bogus OUIs? Have you tried at least setting the "locally administered" bit (the 2's place bit of the first octet of the MAC address)? That's what the IEEE MAC address standards say you're supposed to when you're inventing your own MAC addresses instead of using a properly acquired/registered OUI. 02:00:00:00:00:05 and 02:00:00:00:00:06 are far more acceptable and standards-compliant than using 00:00:00 as your OUI.

Comment: @user1670057 (see updates to my answer) Afterthought: could it that you did set up a default gateway with e.g. a 24bit network mask? In this case, although the subnet is different, the broadcast domains of router and clients overlap. This could explain current behavior.

Comment: The thing that stands out the most are the ethernet addresses, 00:00:00:00:00:05 & 00:00:00:00:00:06. They do not look plausible. If you have changed them, then please tell us.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your setup actually is as you describe it (nothing is accidentally misconfigured): unless the client 10.10.11.1/30 has some information about how to route to 10.10.11.9/30 (via default gateway, static routes etc.), no ICMP packets should be sent out.

Try it on Cisco Paket Tracer. Setup a network with two clients and one switch in between. As long as there is no default gateway configured (and the clients are in different broadcast domains), the client won't even send out any ARP packets.

This means your current configuration provides some sort of "routing resolution" so the ICMP packets are actually being sent and received. Possibly via the default gateway, a static route, etc. Check layer 2, to which MAC address are the frames being set? Directly to the client or to a router? As I wrote in my comment:

> the ICMP package had to be sent through a router, a static route, some
> "exotic" configuration like "proxy-arp" etc. What happens on layer 2?
> How does the IP address gets resolved to a MAC address? I think this
> will lead you to the solution to why there's a response in the first
> place (which shouldn't be).

Why the received packets aren't shown within the ping stats is another matter. Could be a firewall blocking them (my guess since the ping command doesn't give any errors nor confirmations about the individual pings, it just gives you the summary).

The only other explanation I have is that there's some other kind of funky configuration messing up the system (e.g. a second client with the same IP address as the destination and within the broadcast domain as the source etc.). You can check this on layer 2 as well, by comparing the MAC addresses of the frames with those from the actual clients.

**Afterthought**: could it be that you did set up a default gateway, static route etc.? does the router have e.g. a 24bit network mask? In this case, although the subnet is different, the broadcast domains of router and clients overlap. This could explain current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your network is in a bad shape, probably because of
a mixup of netmasks:

- The ICMP request is preceded by a previous ARP request,
  immediately or sometime before.
  Evidently the ARP request succeeded, so some node knew where
  is `10.10.11.9`
  and returned its MAC address, or the ICMP would never have been sent.
- The PING request should have returned
  "net unreachable" (or at least "host unreachable"),
  which it didn't. So the ICMP request was successfully sent and returned
  with a success code.

The question remains why the ping command still reported a 100% packet loss.

I can only theorize that the ping command itself has discarded the answer,
perhaps since it came from another network.

My conclusion is that some other nodes on the network are using
`10.10.11.x/24`, so are delivering the ping, causing a big confusion
for the `10.10.11.1/30` node.

Comment: Thanks alot for your input. 

When i just write "Ping 10.10.11.9", ping simply returns "Network is unreachable". 

I know this is the right configuration since I configured both interfaces on different subnets. The only problem is, while I am running Wireshark and when i simply run the command

"ping 10.10.11.9",
 it simply returns "Network is unreachable".  I wanted to see some ICMP packets failing but didnt see. So i specified the interface in the ping command i-e

"ping -I eth1 10.10.11.9" and then I started getting the above ICMP req and reply while ping is still timing out.

Comment: Instead of ICMP, I see MDNS packets and ICMPv6 Router solicitation

Comment: The IPv4 settings do not pertain to IPv6 that still stays one network. If your router is still on `/24` rather than `/30`, that would explain the results.

Comment: ICMP request is NOT always preceded by an arp request. If an arp entry already exists, there is no need to make a request.

Comment: @Bib: In my tests on Windows this was the case, but perhaps it's not universal.

Comment: I tested it From Windows 2019 server, Linux and a Cisco router. None of them preceded it with an arp request. I suggest you run 2 tests, 30 seconds apart. You will see no arp request before the second batch. If a valid arp entry already exists, no system performs an additional arp request.

Comment: @Bib: No problem, I modified my answer.